# Ruby on Rails - How to replace one has_one association with another without :delete or :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have these two classes:

```
    class Dungeon < ApplicationRecord
      has_one :room
      ...
    end

    class Room < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :dungeon
      ...
    end
```

I want to be able to replace Dungeon's one Room object with another without actually deleting or destroying Dungeon's original Room object. When I try using `update(room: r)`, I get

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to remove the existing associated room. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.
```

What do I need to do to be able to simply replace Dungeon's one room with another?

Comment: Post your database migration for these two objects. You probably have a foreign key constraint in your database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Rails 5 `belongs_to` associations require the associated object to exist (see: [PR introducing this behavior](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937)).

That said: If you want to keep a `room` although it does not have a `dungeon` associated you have to change your `belongs_to` definition to:

```
belongs_to :dungeon, optional: true
```